# "We can't find products matching the selection" in magento 2

Tags: magento, product, reindex, indexer, magento2.4

my site show "We can't find products matching the selection" in category page.

I used the command "bin/magento indexer:reindex", the product appeared. But then it disappeared again and showed the words "We can't find products matching the selection" on the category page. can anyone help me?